# change highcharts detetime label

Tags: highcharts

I have looked at the HighCharts API and I came across dateTimeLabel but I haven't been able to set the label properly. Here is my code, for the options

```
var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'graph',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'KWH Per Phase'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Time Period'
                        },
                        categories:[],
                        type: 'datetime',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                            day: '%e %b'
                        }

                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'KWH Per Phase'
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
                };
```

and the part where I push in the data

```
if (itemNo === 0) { /* first item containes year */
                                options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                            }
```

The datetime is displayed how it is in my csv file "1/2/2014 7:59"

Answer (score 0):

If you have pushed the categories then it doesn't become any dateTime axis. Then it is a normal axis with categorised labels.

For dateTime axis you need to specify the `type: 'datetime'`

and pass the date along with data.

the date should be either a UNIX time stamp or the UTC date format.

examples:

with UTC date
http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/9XWpC/
http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/jFj5w/

timestamp
http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/jFj5w/1/

you can format the labels from the formatter.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you provide me a link to an example with a CSV i have been looking for one but no success so far?

Comment: You need to use item, which contains a time, split it and use Date.UTC() function.